# Elastic Beanstalk: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We had a working Elastic Beanstalk environment, but after adding a config file, we've started getting this error during deploy:

> Error occurred during build: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

The config file looks like this:

```
# .ebextentions/seed.config
container_commands:
  01_set_tenant_gateway:
    command: rake db:seed:set_tenant_gateway
    leader_only: true
    env: our-env
```

The log gives us this:

> 2015-04-09 18:27:48,220 [DEBUG] Running command seed_tenant_gateway
>   2015-04-09 18:27:48,220 [DEBUG] Generating defaults for command
>   seed_tenant_gateway <<<
>
> 2015-04-09 18:27:48,405 [DEBUG] Running test for command
>   seed_tenant_gateway 2015-04-09 18:27:48,406 [ERROR] Unhandled
>   exception during build: dictionary update sequence element #0 has
>   length 1; 2 is required Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 122, in 
>       worklog.build(detail.metadata, configSets)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line
>   117, in build
>       Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line
>   502, in build
>       self.run_config(config, worklog)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line
>   511, in run_config
>       CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py",
>   line 247, in build
>       changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py",
>   line 84, in apply
>       testResult = ProcessHelper(test, env=env, cwd=cwd).call()   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 397, in
>   **init**
>       self._env = dict(env) ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

What might be going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Syntax for *env* key:

```
env: 
    <variable name>: <variable value>
```

2) Also, you need to enclose *command* in quotes:

```
command: "<command to run>"
```

from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html